# when to use double quotes with a variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, variable-substitution

I am in a confusion with what is meant by the double quotes referring to a variable. For example following two scripts gives the same output. What is really meant by the double quotes?

Script1

```
getent passwd | while IFS=: read a b c d e f ; do
echo login "$a" is "$d"
done
```

script 2

```
#! /bin/sh

getent passwd | while IFS=: read a b c d e f ; do

    echo login $a is $d
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), specifically section [5.1 which covers quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html). The reason you double quote variables is because the contents of the variable may include spaces. A space is typically the boundary character which denotes a break in atoms within a string of text for most commands.

There's a good example there that illustrates this point:

*excerpt from the above link*

```
variable2=""    # Empty.

COMMAND $variable2 $variable2 $variable2
                # Executes COMMAND with no arguments. 
COMMAND "$variable2" "$variable2" "$variable2"
                # Executes COMMAND with 3 empty arguments. 
COMMAND "$variable2 $variable2 $variable2"
                # Executes COMMAND with 1 argument (2 spaces).
# Thanks, Stéphane Chazelas.
```

In the above you can see that depending on how you quote the variable it's either no arguments, 3, or 1.

**NOTE:** Thanks to @StéphaneChazelas for providing that feedback to the ABS Guide so that it can work it's way back into this site where he's always participating.

Comment: Is there any scenario where you wouldn't want to enclose a variable with double quotes?