# Content of variable seems to change

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable with a directory path. If I `echo` its content it outputs the right path, but if I try to `cd` it doesn't and it seems to delete the `/home/user/` from the path:

```
[user@project]$ echo $PROJECT_DELIVERY
/home/user/projects/ws/project/delivery/project_name_0.1.0
[user@project]$ cd $PROJECT_DELIVERY
: No such file or directoryuser/projects/ws/project/delivery/project_name_0.1.0
```

This is the content of `printf %s "$PROJECT_DELIVERY" | xxd`

```
[a27503408@ded30325 install]$ printf %s "$PROJECT_DELIVERY" | xxd
0000000: 2f68 6f6d 652f 6132 3735 3033 3430 382f  /home/user/
0000010: 7072 6f6a 6563 7473 2f61 7332 3530 2f41  projects/as250/A
0000020: 5332 3530 5f4d 3135 3533 5f54 4d54 432f  S250_M1553_TMTC/
0000030: 6465 6c69 7665 7279 2f41 5332 3530 5f4d  delivery/AS250_M
0000040: 3135 3533 5f54 4d54 435f 302e 312e 300d  1553_TMTC_0.1.0.
```

Any idea what could be causing this behavior? I'm using bash 4.1.2(1)

Comment: Add double quotes around every variables...

Comment: @GillesQuenot mmm it doesn't solve it

Comment: Can you include the output of `printf %s "$PROJECT_DELIVERY" | xxd`?

Comment: The variable likely contains a carriage return (`\r`) at the end or in the very beginning.

Comment: sounds like a `dos2unix` missing somewhere ...

Comment: @Kusalananda that's the output of the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing CR in the directory name. (See the `0d` as the final character in the hex dump.)

This also explains why the directory path is overwritten by the error message. Normally you would get

```
cd /qwerty
-bash: cd: /qwerty: No such file or directory
```

But you were getting the equivalent of this, where the leading information has been overwritten by the CR and the subsequent error message:

```
cd /qwerty
: No such file or directory
```

Try this to demonstrate the point:

```
echo "$PROJECT_DELIVERY<"
```

You can remove the trailing `\r` character with a construct like this

```
r=$'\r'                                      # Or r=$(printf "\r")
PROJECT_DELIVERY="${PROJECT_DELIVERY%$r}"    # Strip the CR from the end
```

Comment: but why it works when I echo the variable? and how do I fix this?

Comment: @WooWapDaBug it only looks like it works. Try the `echo` statement I suggested in my answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kusalananda commented, your variable contains more than meets the - unattentive - eye.  See the blank line after your echo output?

Comment: the blank line I added it to make it easier to read. I've removed it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there were '\r' and '\n' characters. I removed them with:

```
VARIABLE="$(echo "$VARIABLE"|tr -d '\n'|tr -d '\r')"
```

Comment: There's no `\n` in your string so you don't need to remove it. But you are still not double-quoting your variables. Use `VARIABLE=$(echo "$VARIABLE"|tr -d '\r')` if you must use `tr`.

Comment: @roaima why do I need to double quote them?

Comment: Because [when to use double quotes with a variable in shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78002/when-to-use-double-quotes-with-a-variable-in-shell-script)